# Inconsistent typing [...].map() for point free or with an arrow function

Tags: typescript

See this example:

```
const strings = ['1', '2', 2];
const mapper = (s: string) => parseInt(s, 10);
const numbers1 = strings.map(mapper);
const numbers2 = strings.map(s => mapper(s));
```

With this example, the line with `numbers1` typechecks fine, which it shouldn't because `strings` has the type of `(string | number)[]`, and `mapper` only accepts `string` arguments.

However if I use a lambda at `numbers2` I do get the expected error as `s` is of type `(string | number)` that can't be passed into `mapper`.

Is there a reason for this, or is there maybe some 'strict' configuration to get the expected error, or is it simply a bug?

To run the example see: [playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=const%20strings%20%3D%20%5B'1'%2C%20'2'%2C%202%5D%3B%0D%0Aconst%20mapper%20%3D%20(s%3A%20string)%20%3D%3E%20parseInt(s%2C%2010)%3B%0D%0Aconst%20numbers1%20%3D%20strings.map(mapper)%3B%0D%0Aconst%20numbers2%20%3D%20strings.map(s%20%3D%3E%20mapper(s))%3B)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are similar issues / proposal on TypeScript github (for example: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1394).

Currently you have `(s: string) => any` implicitly cast to `(s: string | number) => any`. And TypeScript compiler for any generic argument think that it can be cast to "more wide" type (covariance). But for function parameters opposite thing should work (contravariance). And currently TypeScript doesn't support it.